Error in bi_class() function: the condition has length > 1 while using Shiny
I am building an RShiny dashboard that allows the user to select two variables which then is plotted onto a bivariate map. This is the code so far:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(biscale)
library(tools)

data <- structure(list(
  mean_pci = c(45676.758, 24152.725, 48797.093, 43445.612, 25898.389, 28334.789, 40320.323, 24833.757, 22664.184, 34335.008), 
  mean_pop = c(2545.349, 9781.295, 6784.606, 2512.415, 4666.243, 3532.699, 4313.023, 8745.735, 6445.338, 5860.371), 
  count_airbnb = c(36, 67, 73, 81, 56, 54, 4, 96, 87, 53), 
  log_mean_price = c(2.285454, 1.820976, 2.112407, 2.157243, 2.341376, 2.235902, 2.503111, 2.368511, 1.818979, 1.795798)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Bivariate maping"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("x_variable", h4("Select x variable:"),
                   choices = c("Mean per capita income" = "mean_pci",
                               "Mean population" = "mean_pop",
                               "Number of airbnbs" = "count_airbnb",
                               "Mean price of airbnbs" = "log_mean_price"),
                   selected = "mean_pci"),
      
      selectInput("y_variable", h4("Select y variable:"),
                  choices = c("Mean per capita income" = "mean_pci",
                              "Mean population" = "mean_pop",
                              "Number of airbnbs" = "count_airbnb",
                              "Mean price of airbnbs" = "log_mean_price"),
                  selected = "mean_pci"),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "800px")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){
  plot_reactive <- reactive({
    
    biClasses <- bi_class(data, x = input$x_variable, y = input$y_variable, style = "quantile", dim = 3)
    
    bi_Map <- ggplot()+
      geom_sf(data = biClasses, mapping = aes(fill = bi_class), color = "black", size = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
      bi_scale_fill(pal = "DkViolet", dim = 3) +
      coord_sf(crs = st_crs(7131), datum = NA) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"),
            plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
      annotation_scale(location = "bl", line_width = 0.2, height = unit(0.05, "in")) +
      annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true",
                             height = unit(1.25, "cm"), width = unit(1.25, "cm"),
                             style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) +
      theme_minimal()
    
    bi_Legend <- bi_legend(pal = "DkViolet", dim = 3, xlab = input$x_variable, ylab = input$y_variable, size = 7)
    
    plot <- ggdraw() +
      draw_plot(bi_Map, 0, 0, 1, 1) +
      draw_plot(bi_Legend, 0.55, 0.358, 0.28, 0.28)
    
    
    })
    
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot_reactive()
  })
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I am having the error: the condition has length > 1, which is happening in this line of code:
biClasses <- bi_class(data, x = input$x_variable, y = input$y_variable, style = "quantile", dim = 3)

Note: ui function works and displays correctly.
It is not happy with the input$x_variable, input$y_variable.
When just plotting the map outside a Shiny app and pass mean_pci and mean_pop in the x and y options, the map displays correctly:
Note this code is not reproducible without full dataset with geometry
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(biscale)

biClasses <- bi_class(data, x = mean_pop, y = mean_pci, style = "quantile", dim = 3)

bi_Map <- ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = biClasses, mapping = aes(fill = bi_class), color = "black", size = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  bi_scale_fill(pal = "DkViolet", dim = 3) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(7131), datum = NA) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), "cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 18, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", line_width = 0.2, height = unit(0.05, "in")) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "tl", which_north = "true",
                         height = unit(1.25, "cm"), width = unit(1.25, "cm"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) +
  theme_minimal()

bi_Legend <- bi_legend(pal = "DkViolet", dim = 3, xlab = "Higher pop", ylab = "Higher pci", size = 7)

plot <- ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(bi_Map, 0, 0, 1, 1) +
  draw_plot(bi_Legend, 0.55, 0.358, 0.28, 0.28)

plot

Traceback details for the error:
> traceback()
13: execCallbacks(timeoutSecs, all, loop$id)
12: run_now(timeoutMs/1000, all = FALSE)
11: service(timeout)
10: serviceApp()
9: ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
8: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = doCaptureStack)
7: domain$wrapSync(expr)
6: promises::with_promise_domain(createStackTracePromiseDomain(), 
       expr)
5: captureStackTraces({
       while (!.globals$stopped) {
           ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
       }
   })
4: ..stacktraceoff..(captureStackTraces({
       while (!.globals$stopped) {
           ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
       }
   }))
3: runApp(x)
2: print.shiny.appobj(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)


The function bi_class() is expecting column names or vectors as its arguments, but you are proving it with strings with the names of columns. This is because, despite your inputs containing the names of the columns, the object input$x_variable is just a string with the name, not the actual column of the dataframe.
Therefore, you need to point your function to the actual columns.
To solve this, we need to use input$x_variable and input$y_variable to actually point to columns in our dataframe.
Use the mutate function to create two new columns based on your text inputs: "var_x" and "var_y". These two columns will be always expected by the bi_class function, so we only need to create them before we pass data to bi_class. But, in order to pass strings as column names, we need to convert strings into symbols, i.e., tell mutate that out text inputs are actually column names with !!sym():
#use your inputs to create new columns
        data2 <- data |>
            #the original columns will be renamed 
            mutate(x_variable = !!sym(input$x_variable), 
                   y_variable = !!sym(input$y_variable))
        
        #then use the newly created variables in your function
        biClasses <- bi_class(data2, x = x_variable, y = y_variable, style = "quantile", dim = 3)

Notice that we need to use the injection operator (!!) and the sym function in order to tell mutate that the strings are actually columns in the dataframe.

Thank you for you suggestions.
I have put in print(input$x_variable) and print(input$y_variable) and they match the column headings. Also the req() functions doesn't fix the issue with the same error coming up.
How can I help in giving reproducible code? As I am mapping I would need to give the geometry column, but this contains a huge list of multipolygon, without this this would cause error. That's why I gave the data link.

For a reproducible example, you can use the {regex} package, or simply slice your dataframe with slice to make it shorter, only select required columns with select, and then use dput to get code to reproduce your dataset. For us to help you, we don't need the plot code, because your error lies before the plot itself. Here are some instructions.

I have updated my original code with an example dataset. I have ran it myself and it comes with the condition > 1 error. Hope this is helpful

Thank you very much! Just reproduced the error, and updated my answer! Its fixed now.

Thank you so much. That has fixed the issue :))
